# Why does my background color menu items stay black, and not change color with my css

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to change my background color on the menu items, but they just stay black all the time. My lines underneath move and are red; it's just the background colors. I am using a twentythirteen theme in WordPress to experiment.

Here is the CSS:

```
nav-menu li a:hover {
    background: pink;
    color: orange;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: pink;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-menu li a::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
}

.nav-menu a:hover::after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting and attach the HTML that reproduces your issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like !important.

```
nav-menu li a:hover {
    background: pink !important;
    //….
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover,
.nav-menu li:focus > a,
.nav-menu li a:focus
 {
  background: pink !important;
   color: orange !important;
  }
```